# How to calculate the number of matching string with external dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, count, match

I've created a dictionary using other source and I'm trying to count the number of matching word and the non-matching word of a sentence.

```
dictionary = ["hello", "good", "happy"]
str1 = ["the dog is happy"]
```

For example above, I want to find out the number of word in str1 that is matching with the dictionary and the number of non-matching, the result would be something like number of matching = 1 and number of non-matching = 3. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Just write some code. And see [ask].

Comment: @Robert Noted. So sorry that I'm new to Python as well as the community here, would check on it then. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = ["hello", "good", "happy"]
s = "the dog is happy"
```

note: i turned `["the dog is happy"]` --> `"the dog is happy"` as the list is unnecessary

```
l = [i in d for i in s.split(' ')]
matching = l.count(True)  # can also use sum(l)
non_matching = l.count(False)
```

Comment: Tysm, it works exactly like how I want.